# Multi steps ahead prediction for multiple outputs using Keras

Tags: python, deep-learning, time-series, keras, lstm

I am new to deep learning and LSTM (with keras). I am trying to solve a multistep ahead time series prediction. I have 3 time series: A, B and C and I want to predict the values of C. I am training an LSTM feeding 3 steps back data points to predict the next 3 steps in the future. 
The input data looks like:

```
X = [[[A0, B0, C0],[A1, B1, C1],[A2, B2, C2]],[[ ...]]]
```

with dimensions: `(1000, 3, 3)`. The output is:

```
y = [[C3, C4, C5],[C4, C5, C6],...]
```

with dimensions: `(1000, 3)`.

I am using a simple LSTM with 1 hidden layer (50 neurons).
I set up an LSTM with keras as:

```
n_features = 3
neurons = 50
ahead = 3
model = Sequential()
model.add(LSTM(input_dim=n_features, output_dim=neurons))
model.add(Dropout(.2))
model.add(Dense(input_dim=neurons, output_dim=ahead))
model.add(Activation('linear'))
model.compile(loss='mae', optimizer='adam')
model.fit(X, y, epochs=50)
```

This model works fine. Now, I'd like to predict the values of B as well (using the same input). So I tried to reshape the output in a similar way as I did for the training that has multiple features:

```
 y = [[[B3, C3],[B4, C4],[B5, C5]],[[ ...]]]
```

so that it has dimensions: `(1000, 3, 2)`. However, this gives me an error:

```
Error when checking target: expected activation_5 to have 2 dimensions, 
but got array with shape (1000, 3, 2)
```

I guess the structure of the network needs to change. I tried to modify `model.add(Dense(input_dim=neurons, output_dim=ahead))` with no success. Should I reshape the `y` differently? Is the structure of the network wrong?

Comment: I think the idea is correct but the code is wrong. An LSTM layer takes a 3D tensor as input and returns a 2D tensor, as stated [here](https://keras.io/layers/recurrent). To make it return a 3D tensor you need to set `return_sequence=True`.

Comment: By setting output_dim as 3 on the final Dense layer, aren't you essentially asking it to predict the output as a single time step with 3 different features instead of 3 separate time steps with a single feature?